# Fragment onCreateView getting called multiple time so that new instance of fragment is created every time

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2, fragment-oncreateview

I am trying to add the fragments on page change of view pager. but every time when i scroll the view pager, new instant of fragment is created.

```
public void initializeViewPager(int currentPage, String selectedCardNumber) {
    currentPosition = currentPage;
    FragmentPagerAdapter journeyViewPagerAdapter =
            new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


    ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener onPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            //Default Implementation
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            currentPosition = position;
            addFragments(position, selectedCardNumber);
            handleScrollState();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            //Default Implementation
        }
    };

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(onPageChangeListener);
    initCarousalAdapter();

}
```

addFragments() method

```
private void addFragments(int position, final String selectedCardNumber) {

    FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt(ApplicationConstants.SELECTED__TYPE, position);
    bundle.putString(DataConstants.SELECTED__NUMBER, selectedCardNumber);

    switch (position) {
        case 1:
            OffersFragmentOne fragment = OffersFragmentOne.getInstance();
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            fragTransaction.replace(R.id.btmt_fragment_container, fragment);
            break;

        case 2:
            OffersFragmentTwo mtFragment = OffersFragmentTwo.getInstance();
            mtFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            fragTransaction.replace(R.id.btmt_fragment_container, mtFragment);
            break;

        case 3:
            OffersFragmentThree poFragment = OffersFragmentThree.getInstance();
            poFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            fragTransaction.replace(R.id.btmt_fragment_container, poFragment);
            break;
        default:
            //Default Implementation
    }

    fragTransaction.commit();
}
```

getInstance() method

```
private static OffersFragmentOne offersFragmentOne;

public static OffersFragmentOne getInstance() {
    if (OffersFragmentOne == null) {
        offersFragmentOne = new OffersFragmentOne();
    }
    return offersFragmentOne;
}
```

ViewPagerAdapter.java

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private final int[] carousalImages = {R.drawable.ic_po_carousal_banner, 
R.drawable.ic_bt_carousal_banner,
    R.drawable.ic_mt_carousal_banner, R.drawable.ic_po_carousal_banner, 
R.drawable.ic_bt_carousal_banner};

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    super(fragmentManager);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    CarousalFragment frag = new CarousalFragment();
    CarousalFragmentPresenter.createAndAttach(frag, carousalImages[position]);
    return frag;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return carousalImages != null ? carousalImages.length : 0;
}
}
```

Comment: you are creating new instances in `addFragments()` every time
must create one instance retain in activity or adapter and reuse that again and again

Comment: I am using getInstance() method which is static and creating fragment instance only one time. or is there any other way @Hanzala

Comment: Can you share code of getInstance method?

Comment: share `ViewPagerAdapter` code

Comment: I noticed you are not using any adapter for view pager you are replacing fragments manually in `addFragments()` method

Comment: I have updated my question please check @KishoreJethava

Comment: added getInstance method code @NatigBabayev

Comment: It's not quite clear what your overall setup is, but just because you're using the same `Fragment` instances, that does not mean that their `View`s won't be destroyed and recreated between transactions.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating the fragment instances in the container activity or so of the view pager? That way they should be created only when the container is created.

EDIT: Adding example code.
Example:

```
public class ContainerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FragmentOne fragmentOne;
    private FragmentTwo fragmentTwo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.container_with_view_pager);
        fragmentOne = FragmentOne.getInstance();
        fragmentTwo = FragmentTwo.getInstance();

        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(fragmentOne, "Fragment One");
        adapter.addFragment(fragmentTwo, "Fragment Two");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have any example for this?

Answer (score 0):

You should write your switch case in `getItem` and don't required `bundle` and fragment transaction because `getItem` itself returns selected `Fragment` and will bind with `ViewPager`

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
switch (position) {
    case 0:
        CarousalFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        OffersFragmentOne.getInstance();
        break;

    case 2:
        OffersFragmentTwo.getInstance();

        break;

    case 3:
        OffersFragmentThree.getInstance();
        break;
    default:
        //Default Implementation
}
}
```

`OnPageChangeListener` just give you the position of selected and scrolled item or fragment, so don't required to add fragment from `onPageSelected`

```
ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener onPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        //Default Implementation
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        //Default Implementation
    }
};
```

Comment: Have you found solution?